# doctrine querybuilder get nearest datetime

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I've been looking for hours to get the right syntax for the doctrine query builder. I need to get the oldest value in the DB.

colums:

```
id, dateCreated, value
```

query: (that doesn't works)

```
->select('c')
->where(
    $qb->expr()->eq('c.dateCreated', $qb->expr()->min('c.dateCreated')) 
)
```

can someone tells me how to build the right query for my need please. Thanks guys!

Comment: Just sort the result set by `dateCreated` with addition of limiting to 1 result and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You should just sort returned values and only get the first one (depending on the ordering)

```
$select('c')->orderBy('c.expDate', 'ASC')->setMaxResults(1);
```